# Set a Form name for use in functions

Tags: vba, ms-access, set

I have a number of  forms that calles the same functions(s) in order to update tables and check some thing. 
When I open a form I set the form name variable:

```
Set FrmNamn = Forms!Fathantering_Frm
```

And then I call the function:

Tomt_Formulär

```
Function Tomt_Formulär()
FrmNamn!Hämta_MätNr.Enabled = False
FrmNamn!Skapa_AvfBesk.Enabled = False
FrmNamn!Lasta_Emb.Enabled = False
End Function
```

This works perfect! :)

Now I have created a Navigation form for all this different forms and Access don't accept the FrmNamn variable.

How should i Set the FrmNamn? I have tried eveything but I can't figure it out :(

Comment: [Please apply the appropriate tags to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Ok! i'm new in this forum so I guess I have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as an argument:

```
TomtFormulär(Forms!Fathantering_Frm)

Function TomtFormulär(ByRef frm As Form)

    frm!Hämta_MätNr.Enabled = False
    frm!Skapa_AvfBesk.Enabled = False
    frm!Lasta_Emb.Enabled = False

End Function
```

Also, avoid underscores in function names.

To address a subform:

```
TomtFormulär(Forms!NameOfParentForm!NameOfSubformCONTROL.Form)
```

Comment: I tried this and get the message "Access cannot find the form Fathantering_Frm". It must be because the form is a subform in the Navigation form that is called Nav_Hant.

Comment: Thank you so much, you put me in the right direction. I had to change the code for setting the form name to <code>Set FrmNamn = Forms!Nav_Hant!NavUnd.Form</code>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, you put me in the right direction. I had to change the code for setting the form name to:

```
Set FrmNamn = Forms!Nav_Hant!NavUnd.Form
```

The navigation form is named "Nav_Hant" and the subform is named "NavUnd". It looks like I don't have to include the form "Fathantering_Frm"
I think this will work. I will test it a bit more :)